# Вставка в корень дерева

Tags: python

не получается сделать добавление в корень

```
class node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0
    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

class tree:
    def __init__(self, key = None, size = 0, left = None, right = None):
        self.key = key
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.size = size
    def add(self, other):
        if self.key == None:
            self.key = other
            self.size = 1
            self.right = tree()
            self.left = tree()
        else:
            if other > self.key:
                return self.right.add(other)
            else:
                return self.left.add(other)
        self.size = self.len()
    def find(self, key):
        if self.key == None:
            return 0
        else:
            if key == self.key:
                return 1
            elif key > self.key:
                return self.right.find(key)
            else:
                return self.left.find(key)
    def getsize(self):
        if self.key == None:
            return 0
        return self.size
    def fixsize(self):
        self.size = self.left.getsize() + self.right.getsize() + 1
        return self.size
    def len(self):
        if self.key == None:
            return 0
        else:
            #self.size = self.left.len() + self.right.len() + 1
            return self.left.len() + self.right.len() + 1
    def rotateright(self): #правый поворот вокруг узла
        if self.left == None:
            return self
        s = self.size
        root = self.left
        self.left = root.right
        root.right = self
        root.size = s
        return root
    def rotateleft(self): #левый поворот вокруг узла
        if self.right == None:
            return self
        s = self.size
        root = self.right
        self.right = root.left
        root.left = self
        root.size = s
        return root
    def addroot(self, key): #вставка нового узла с ключем key в корень
        if self.key == None:
            self.key = key
            self.size = 1
            self.right = tree()
            self.left = tree()
        elif self.key > key:
            self.left = self.left.addroot(key)
            s = self.rotateright()
            return s
        else:
            self.right = self.right.addroot(key)
            s = self.rotateleft()
            return s

a = tree()
a.add(5)
a.add(3)
a.add(8)
a.add(7)
a.add(10)
print()
print(a.len())
print()
print(a.key)
a.add(6)
a = a.rotateleft()
a = a.rotateleft()
a = a.addroot(9)
print(a.key)
```

Результат:

```
     5
     5
     8
```

Comment: Вообще по логике tree должно быть контейнером, в котором хранится только ссылка на корень, без всяких "левых" и "правых" ссылок. А в node уже должны быть ссылки на "левый" и "правый" элемент. При вставке в корень элемент добавляется на место старого корня внутри tree.

Answer (score 0):

Вот. Также переработан класс `tree`.

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, root=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.root = root
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def append(self, item):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = item
            return None
        tree = self

        while True:
            if tree.root >= item:
                if tree.right is None:
                    tree.right = Tree(item)
                    return None
                else:
                    tree = tree.right
            else:
                if tree.left is None:
                    tree.left = Tree(item)
                    return None
                else:
                    tree = tree.left

    def set_root(self, root):
        old_root, self.root = self.root, root
        if (self.left is not None) and (self.root >= self.left.root):
            self.left, self.right = self.right, self.left
        self.append(old_root)

    def __len__(self):
        return sum(1 for _ in self)

    def __iter__(self):
        if self.left is not None:
            yield from self.left
        if self.root is not None:
            yield self.root
        if self.right is not None:
            yield from self.right

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Tree({}, {}, {})'.format(self.root, self.left, self.right)


tree = Tree()
tree.append(5)
tree.append(3)
tree.append(8)
tree.append(7)
tree.append(10)
tree.set_root(3)

print('tree', tree)
print('list(tree)', list(tree))
```

Comment: В методе rotate независимо от значения аргумента результат операции будет один и тот же.

Comment: @insolor , fixed